# Get the value of the input text field and substring it

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please visit my fiddle 1st: http://jsfiddle.net/vHLXX/

This is phone no. input field, if the length is 11 (value of the text input field) on click on the submit button alerts "yes" else "no".

Now, I want if the 1st three string isn't 011 i want alert "invalid!"

How can I get this (with jquery)?

here is the html:

```
<span>enter you mobile no.</span>
<input  maxlength="11" size="11" type="text" class="main-input" value=""/>
<input type="button" class="Create" value="Submit">
```

and Jquery Code:

```
$('.main-input').on('keyup', function () {
    values = $(this).val();
    newValue = values.substring();
}); 
$('.Create').click(function () {   
    if (values.length === 11) {
        alert("yes");
    } else {
        alert("no");
    };
});
```

PS: Could edit you my fiddle?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (values.indexOf("011") != 0)
  alert("invalid!");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.main-input').on('keyup', function () {
    values = $(this).val();
    newValue = values.substring();
}); 

$('.Create').click(function () {
    if(values.indexOf("011") !== 0){
        alert("invalid!");
        return;
    }
    if (values.length === 11) {
        alert("yes");
    } else {
        alert("no");
    };
});
```

Above codes firstly, check the input text if it starts with `011`, if not, alert("invalid!").
If so, keep checking if its length is 11.